# how to interrupt current executing spring scheduler thread

Tags: spring, spring-scheduled

I have multiple jobs running by spring quartz scheduler. each job is running inside re-entrant lock. yesterday some how one of my job blocked for ever and never come out of lock. I use annotations @Scheduled(cron="${email.alert.cron}") to invoke jobs. is there any way i can configure job come out of lock after specific time?

Comment: What locking mechanism are you using? Locks? Object.wait() ?

Comment: Reentrantlock's  lock.lock(); and i have lock.unlock(); in finally block

Comment: Ok, so one of your Job's waited for the lock.lock() forever? If so, then you have had a deadlock. Have you managed to create a thread dump for this particular JVM? You would be able to tell which thread was waiting for which lock.